# Need help ModelMultipleChoiceField error in Django

Tags: python, django

I am using a ModelMultipleChoiceField to do something but I am getting an error saying:

```
AttributeError at /auth_users/

'MultipleChoiceField' object has no attribute 'all'
```

My **form** is:

```
class AuthUserCheckbox(forms.Form):

    choice = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        user_email = self.user.email.split('@')[1]
        super(AuthUserCheckbox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice'].queryset = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=[
                (i.email, i.email)
                for i in User.objects.filter(
                    is_active=False,
                    email__icontains=user_email
                )
            ]
        )
```

My **view** is:

```
@login_required
def auth_users(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthUserCheckbox(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            AuthUserCheckbox.auth_users(form)
            return render(request, 'todoapp/success.html')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h3>Authorization failed</h3>')
    return render(request, 'todoapp/auth_users.html', context={'form': AuthUserCheckbox(user=request.user)})
```

Where am I going wrong ? this error has been bugging me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign a `MultipleChoiceField` to the queryset of your `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, but you need to assign a queryset.

For example like that:

```python
class AuthUserCheckbox(forms.Form):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.fields['choice'].queryset = User.objects.filter(
            is_active=False,
            email__icontains=user_email,
        )
```

Comment: Yes that was the thing I was doing wrong. Its working fine now. Thanks a lot :)